# TOAD Schema browser thousand separator

Tags: oracle, toad

is it possible to display data in TOADs schemebrowser with thousand separator? i.e. one setting so all tables are displayed with thousand separator.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, as far as I can tell.

If you search TOAD's options for "thousand", you'll find the "Thousand Separator" in "General" set of options:

[image]

But, it just says which character (comma or dot) acts as a thousands separator so that you could use e.g.

```
select to_char(salary, '999G990D00') from employees
                           ^   ^
                           |   |
                  thousands    decimal separator
```

It doesn't affect data displayed in the "Data" tab of the Schema Browser (or  Editor's "Data Grid").